# SQL - Tracking the amount of time speed is 0 for longer than 2 minutes in SQL

Tags: sql, timestamp

I want to get below points from the log of driver's trip data.

1. Number of stoppage where speed is 0 for longer than 2 minutes.
2. Number of minutes stopped.

Below is sample data

```
|   rowid   |   DriverName  |   TripID  |   TripLogSpeed    |   TripLogTime |
    |   --- |   --- |   --- |   --- |   --- |
    |   1   |   Driver1 |   1   |   12.66km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:07:22 AM    |
    |   2   |   Driver1 |   1   |   12.48km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:08:04 AM    |
    |   3   |   Driver1 |   1   |   5.5km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:08:49 AM    |
    |   4   |   Driver1 |   1   |   6.48km/hr   |   2/24/2021 6:09:09 AM    |
    |   5   |   Driver1 |   1   |   34.41km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:09:30 AM    |
    |   6   |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:10:10 AM    |
    |   7   |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:10:33 AM    |
    |   8   |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:11:15 AM    |
    |   9   |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:11:35 AM    |
    |   10  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:13:07 AM    |
    |   11  |   Driver1 |   1   |   9.7km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:13:28 AM    |
    |   12  |   Driver1 |   1   |   38.53km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:13:48 AM    |
    |   13  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:14:08 AM    |
    |   14  |   Driver1 |   1   |   56.19km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:14:29 AM    |
    |   15  |   Driver1 |   1   |   36.69km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:14:50 AM    |
    |   16  |   Driver1 |   1   |   65.45km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:15:11 AM    |
    |   17  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:15:32 AM    |
    |   18  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:15:52 AM    |
    |   19  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:16:13 AM    |
    |   20  |   Driver1 |   1   |   54.05km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:16:33 AM    |
    |   21  |   Driver1 |   1   |   59.77km/hr  |   2/24/2021 6:16:53 AM    |
    |   22  |   Driver1 |   1   |   0.0km/hr    |   2/24/2021 6:17:14 AM    |
```

.. and so on. It can be 1000 records.

So what is the best way to track stoppage.

Thank You for the help!

Comment: Please explain how the timing of a stop is determined.  If there is only one `0`, is the stop instantaneous?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. from the given sample data, from RowID 6 to 10 speed is 0 so calculate the total stop time and if its greater than 2 min then count as 1 stop. and if there is only one record found as 0 but the time it stopped is greater than 2 min then yes count as another stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  To get the stops, then use the difference of row numbers:

```
select tripid, driverid, min(triplogtime), max(triplogtime)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tripid, driverid order by triplogtime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by tripid, ddriverid, triplogspeed order by triplogtime) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where triplogspeed = 0
group by tripid, driverid, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
having max(triplogtime) > min(triplogtime) + interval '2 minute';
```

Note that this users standard SQL date functions.

You can use this as a subquery or CTE to get a summary with the count and total time.  However, because date functions are so database-specific, I'm not going to provide specific code.